# Why did the author for the same sentences chooe gerund one time and infinitive without to for the second one

Tags: gerunds

When I saw the........  **open** for the.......... a couple of years ago, the band was totally new for me

I saw you in Berlin, **opening** for........

I wonder if both sentences have the same meaning? And why one is gerund and not the other. Both sentences have the same author . The first one is a narrative  introducing an interview of the band and the second one is from the interview, it is the beginning of the first question .

Comment: Please post the complete sentences.

Comment: The first one is complete and the second one add (you guys killed it that night) and both refer to the same event